# Package name typed twice for hosted Pub packages

Tags: dart, dart-pub

In regards to this [Pub Dependencies](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/dependencies.html) page and this code snippet:

```
dependencies:
  transmogrify:
    hosted:
      name: transmogrify
      url: http://some-package-server.com
```

Why does the value of `name` exist both under `dependencies` and as a mapping under `hosted`? Are they ever different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was consider to remove the requirement to add the name twice, but was dropped because it didn't seem to be used a lot and was considered a breaking change.

For more details see

- https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/6677
- https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/issues/272

If this is an issue for you just add a comment on 6677 and ask to reopen the issue.